# jQuery find all li with an id starting with total

Tags: jquery

I have the below but want to only loop through lines in #lines which have an id starting with total

```
$("#lines li").each(function() {
}
```

any ideas?

Lee

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$("#lines li[id^=total]").each(function() { ... });
```