# how to give jquery id dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Checkboxes in table1(#tbl1) in jsp created dynamically using ajax and jquery with id like : id="123" (firstId)

```
$.each(json, function(idx, obj) {

$("#tbl1").append('<input type="checkbox" id='+obj.firstId+' onclick=nextPopulate('+obj.firstId+'); >'); }
```

In table2(#tbl2), checkboxes is created on check of checkboxes in tbl1 and whose id will be :

id="123-001" (firstId-secondId)

```
$.each(json, function(idx, obj) {

$("#tbl2").append('<input type="checkbox" id="'+firstId+'-'+secondId+'" >'); }
```

In my javascript, i'm using an ajax call to remove checkboxes in tbl2 if checkbox in tbl1 is unchecked.

The id's of second set of checkboxes will be like : "123-001" ,"123-002", "123-003", "456-001"

So,to remove all checkboxes from tbl2 whose id starts with firstId (123), if checkbox with id 123 is unchecked in tbl1.

How can i do this ?

I can use .empty(). But how to specify id as 'starts with firstId' (123)

I'm trying:

```
if(!($('#'+firstId).is(':checked'))){

    $('#'+firstId'-').empty();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery ID starts with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413841/jquery-id-starts-with) -- please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: you can use class for the second checkbox list. Like class="123" for first 3 check boxes and class="456" for the last one..

Comment: Duplicate of [Wildcards in jQuery selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5376431/218196)

Comment: and [Find html element which id starts with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298730/find-html-element-which-id-starts-with)

Comment: and [jQuery find all li with an id starting with total](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125324/jquery-find-all-li-with-an-id-starting-with-total)

Comment: and [Function for all the ids that starting with “abc_google_” or “abc_facebook_”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18041041/218196)

Comment: and [How to get checkbox which starts with specific id](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15964029/218196)

Comment: All found via http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[jquery]+starts+with+id

Comment: @FelixKling This question is not a duplicate as i cannot hardcode the id. So, i need the correct syntax to take the id dynamically.

Comment: @beauflitz: You already know how to do that, exactly like in your code. You just have to combine it with the solution in the other answers. Shouldn't be so difficult. FWIW, the first question I linked to has exactly the solution you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413841/jquery-id-starts-with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("[id^=check"+webId+"]").fn();
```

Here, check is a string which we hardcode and webClassId is dynamically taken.

So,eg: id starts with check101 will be considered.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple. Use the attr Selector:

```
$('[id^=123]')
```

Comment: I cannot hardcode as 123- . It should be firstId - . what is the syntax for this ?

firstId will have the id.

Comment: See this: $('[id^=' + firstId + ']')

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('[id^=123-]:not(:checked)').empty();
```

Or, you can use remove

```
$('[id^=123-]:not(:checked)').remove();
```

You can also try call .not(':checked');

```
$('[id^=123-]').not(':checked').remove();
```

**Description:** Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

Comment: I cannot hardcode as 123- . It should be firstId - . what is the syntax for this ?

firstId will have the id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`^`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
if(!($('[$id^="firstId"]').is(':checked'))){

    $(this).empty();
```

Comment: I cannot hardcode as 123- . It should be firstId - . what is the syntax for this ?

firstId will have the id.